# Querying Solr in different than English language

Tags: solr, indexing, querying

I have to admit that solr rocks. But the most important is the community response. Thank you once again!

I hade made an index collection in English. I had build that for learning purposes. Now i want to index and query in Greek language. I noticed that querying Greek collections isn't as successful as in English one. Can you explain way? How queries in Greek can be successful? Is there any special Solr configuration for languages like Greek?

Notice that this language has accents, apostrophes and comas.

I will be glad to have a pointer or answer.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starters [the ones specific for Greek in the solr analysis page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Greek)